# Connect To Sock file failed. Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: django, nginx, jmeter, gunicorn

I am setting up a Django server with Nginx, Gunicorn and Django. I follewed this link (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). My server starts working correctly as when I hit my services with Postman or Browser, I am getting response. My Nginx file looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server_ip;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/frt/project/project/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/frt/project/project/project.sock;
    }
}
```

But when I run load test on this server with JMeter, In almost 40% requests, I get "Bad Gateway" error. I look into logs and below is the error

> 2017/10/09 08:11:11 [error] 7777#7777: *3153 connect() to
>   unix:/home/frt/project/project/project.sock failed (11: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client:
>   192.168.23.83, server: 192.168.3.217, request: "GET /api/posts/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://unix:/home/frt/project/project/project.sock:/api/posts/",
>   host: "192.168.3.217"

I am running simple test plan with 3000 threads and ramp up time of 30 seconds.

Comment: add more details of your test plan, how many threads ?, ramp up period / timers /delays between request...

Comment: @user7294900 I have added test details.

Comment: > Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed. from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html

Comment: Thanks. I will check with these settings and post my result.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your application simply cannot handle the load, there are too many possible reasons.

The most obvious could be:

- Lack of resources (i.e CPU or RAM). I would recommend setting up the monitoring of baseline health metrics on the application under test side so you could see if there is enough headroom for your application and if errors or high response time or low throughput are caused by too high memory consumption or swapping. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for details.
- Improper configuration. Inspect your `nginx.conf` file and see i.e. if [`worker_rlimit_nofile` setting](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_rlimit_nofile) has high enough value. See [Tuning NGINX for Performance](https://www.nginx.com/blog/tuning-nginx/) for more information. Same applies to [PostgreSQL database](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server)
- Bad quality of your Django application (inefficient algorithms, large objects in memory, etc.) You might want to use [Python profiling tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) while load test is running to see the most memory/cpu intensive functions and look what can be done to optimize them.